# Codeigniter Populating Drop-Down Performance

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in which I am populating a drop-down with about 100k items.

Obviously this is causing my page to hang for a bit while it's rendering.

```
public function GetOrderDropDown($id){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    $qry = $CI->db->query("Select orderID, CONCAT('Order ID: ', orderID) As OrderName From vwSelectOrders Order By orderStarted Desc", FALSE);                    
    $res = $qry->result_array();
    if($res){
        $rCt = count($res);
        echo '<option value="0">- Please select an order -</option>';
        for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i){
            $sel = ($id == $res[$i]['orderID']) ? ' selected="selected"': null;
            echo '<option value="' . $res[$i]['orderID'] . '"' . $sel . '>' . $res[$i]['OrderName'] . '</option>';
            if($i % 50 === 0){
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The query itself runs pretty quick when applied in SQL MS, in fact when I `print_r` the returned array it's still pretty quick.  So I thought that by adding in a flush of the response at every 50 iterations would do the trick... and it does seem to hang less, but... I wonder if it could be better.

This particular function is called in an ajaxed loaded page that displays a Loading graphic while the page is loaded... maybe I can force it to wait until the page is fully ready to be displayed?

```
// Load in a page
function LoadPage($url, $where){
    var $loading = '<div class="pageLoader">Loading...<br /><img src="/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..." height="11" width="16" /></div>';
    var $container = jQuery((typeof($where) !== 'undefined') ? $where : '#content-container');
    var $t = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var options = {
            url: $url + '?_=' + $t,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
                    $container.slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $container.slideDown('fast').html($loading);    
                    });
                },
            success: function(data, status, jqXhr){
                $container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                    $container.slideDown('fast').html(data);    
                });
            },
            complete: function(jqXhr, status){},
            error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
                $container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                    $container.slideDown('fast').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-4x pull-left"></i><p><strong>Danger Will Robinson!</strong><br />There was an issue pulling in this page. Our support team has been notified, please check back later.</p></div>');    
                });
            }
        };
    jQuery.ajax(options);
}
```

What else could I do, Firefox actually becomes un-responsive while it is loading...?

Comment: one other way you can get all the orders in model first and then render in your view. And in render if you have lot of records then you can use lazyload etc...

Comment: lazyload? I've not seen anything like that in Codeigniter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact You shouldn't use `<select>` for 100k items. That's not user-fiendly. Try to search autocomplete solutions.

About Your question: no, You can't add element with 100k child nodes without overloading browser.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but I am given what I am given, and when the boss says no more JS than what's there, I can only do so much...

Comment: I was actually thinking I could wait until `complete` fires of the `.ajax` function to push in the content...

Comment: @o7thWebDesign also You can send and get not html, but json, collect it on client-side and rebuild Your select (You'll add not all list in one time, but 100k times 1 item). Not sure, but I think it'll work

Comment: I would, but I would have to build the entire html from the json returned.  It's not the function that's called in via ajax... it's a form page, and in the form this function is called.

Comment: maybe I should do it like that though... pull the function in with ajax... display the loader graphic for that particular item until it's `ready` and then render the drop-down via the JSON

Comment: @o7thWebDesign yep. Also You'll transfer smaller data via ajax. Pretty  good for slow connections. And even more (for fanatics): You can transfer CSV file, parse it on client-side and set updated select-tag :)

Comment: can I direct you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941692/pulling-in-json-via-ajax-to-populate-a-drop-down